As a product Owner can I tell a developer to seek help before they submit pull request in JIRA?
My organization somewhat implemented Agile but assigned Product Owners to also be the Scrum Master. In one of my scrum meetings, one of the developers said they did not have experience in a certain concept so I recommended they get with a more senior developer to seek help. Fast forward to todays scrum meeting, the developer stated the pull request is submitted but did not get with the senior developer. I go into the code repository and I saw the the dev is asking other reviewers for feedback to determine if anything was missed.
As dual hatted role, can i encourage/ tell the developer to remove the pull request and get with the senior developer for their guidance?

It is not the product owners job to tell anyone on the developer team how to work. So wearing the product owner hat, that is a strict no.
As a Scrum Master it is your job to assist with the Scrum process as well as any rules your team themselves may have defined. Scrum says nothing about pull requests or talking to seniors. Did you team define any such rules? If so, remind them of those rules. If not, again, this is a strong no.
How the product is developed is the development teams responsibility.
If you have a problem with the quality of the outcome, for example if it has too many bugs or doesn't work correctly to your requirements, you as the product owner can give that feedback to the team and expect change.
As a Scrum Master, if the lack of quality comes up in the retrospective, you can moderate a debate on how to improve it. You can bring in your own experience for example if you have seen a solution to this problem on another team, you could bring that into the discussion. Maybe your team likes it. Maybe not and they come up with their own solution.
But in the end, it is the development teams decision. If they think a pull request is a good tool to solve this and it works... then that's the way it is.

I wouldn't tell the developer to do something in situations like this.
My course of action is to bring things like this up during the retrospective at the end of the sprint. What the team commits to at the beginning of the sprint is an outcome; if that outcome is achieved by the end of the sprint, then that's a real achievement. If the team doesn't reach their sprint goal, it's time to discuss what could have gone better in the retrospective. And even if the story gets completed in the sprint, it might be worth asking how the rest of the team felt about the dev asking in the code review. That can lead to a good discussion between the developers on improving their process.

Depending on the work culture of your organization, there could be different approaches. If the boundaries are set clearly, then I would say casually notify the Senior Developer on the situation and leave it at that. However, if the organization fosters an owner mentality, it is best to resolve the issue by getting the right team involved.
In my view, the frameworks, methodologies are guidelines. The objective is not whether we followed the rules, the objective is to achieve the goal of our project.
